# AWX cannot access its own REST API (Name or service not known)

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, ansible-awx

I am running `awx-operator` on a k3 cluster.
I have a role, `update_host_group`, that tries to use the AWX REST API to manipulate Ansible groups.

```
---
- name: Update Ansible Tower inventory
  uri:
    url: https://awx.example.com/api/v2/groups/36/hosts
    user: "{{ admin_username }}"
    password: "{{ admin_password }}"
    method: 'POST'
    body: '{ "name" : "{{ update_ati_fqdn }}" }'
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 201
    body_format: json
    validate_certs: no
```

I created an inventory named "AWX Meta Inventory" which has just one host, `localhost`.
I also created a job template: "Run Update Host Group Playbook" that executes a playbook
that uses the role, `update_host_group`.  When I launch this template I get this error:

```
TASK [update_host_group : Update Ansible Tower inventory] **********************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 0, "msg": "Status code was
 -1 and not [201]: Request failed: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>", 
"redirected": false, "status": -1, "url": "https://awx.example.com"}
```

Note: Obvisouly don't actually use `example.com`.  I use my real domain name.

UPDATE:
I have tried adding `hostAliases` to my kubernetes but I am not well versed in k* admin.  I looked at the docs here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/network/customize-hosts-file-for-pods/

But of course that doesn't tell where in the `awx` deployment to add the `hostAliases` stanza. So I am just guessing and breaking things.  Does anyone know where I need to put my `hostAliases`?

Comment: Is the AWX REST API accessible in general? If you use curl for such a call, how it behaves then? What would there be the response? It looks like that who is executing the task can’t resolve the name via DNS.

Comment: If I log on to one of the k3 nodes I can `curl` to that url no problem and get a 200 response and database.  Provided I use curl flags `-L`, `-k` and of course the correct creds via the `-u` flag.  But I am not sure if that matters.  How can check if my execution environment container can do the name resolution?

Comment: Because of lack of test environments I do not have an answer for that. Maybe someone else has ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more sort of a workaround.  I am sure there is probably a better solution. I read the documentation here: https://docs.ansible.com/automation-controller/latest/html/administration/containers_instance_groups.html#customize-the-pod-spec

Then I:

- Logged into my AWX Web UI
- Navigated to Administration > Instance Groups
- clicked on the pencil icon to edit the *default* instance group
- clicked the *Customize pod specification* radio button
- and then added these lines just above the `containers:` line:

```
hostAliases:
  - hostnames:
    - awx.example.com
    ip: 10.0.3.52
```

then click the apply button and my task worked (had to update the `status_code` to look for status code 204).